# Count number of CCNodes of a certain class on a layer

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c, xcode

Pretty simple question. I'm working in Objective C (cocos2d) and I'm trying to count the number of a sprites of a certain class are present on the current layer being displayed. For example, I have a class named `Seal` which is a subclass of of `CCNode` and in my current layer I want to count how many instances of type `Seal` are present.

I know how to count the number of children of the layer by doing

```
int numberChildren = [[self children] count];
```

which correctly returns the number of children on the layer. But I just want the number of `Seal`s on my layer. How could I do this? Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as ryrich said, however the actual code on Objective-C would be something like this: 
*(Assuming your CCNode class is called "Seal")*

```
int sealCounter = 0;
for (id *node in self.children) {
    if ([node isKindOfClass:[Seal class]]) {
        sealCounter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I come from a C# background, so I can't write you the code (don't want to give you gross, translated Objective-C code :))

But what you could do is loop through the Children (`[self children]`), check if they can be casted as a `Seal`. If the casted object is not `null`, increment a counter. Then just return the counter after the loop is finished.

Hope this helps!